# Arduino Due and MPL3115A2 (SparkFun)

Tags: arduino, sensors, altitude, arduino-ide

I am using an [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue) board, and I would like to interface it with an altitude sensor.
My hardware connections are:

- Pin 20 goes to SDA of sensor
- Pin 21 goes to SCL of sensor
- V<sub>cc</sub> of the sensor is connected to 3.3 V and GND is connected to GND. INT pins are left open, and I used this code:

https://github.com/sparkfun/MPL3115A2_Breakout/blob/master/firmware/mpl3115a2/mpl3115a2.ino

My problem is that serial monitor only shows [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C).

What could be wrong?

Comment: The GitHub link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the wiring is correct and post the sketch you have loaded on your Arduino. The one of GitHub is correct, so maybe you have changed something in your one.